# Object Value Assignment from one Serializable Object to another

Tags: java

I have two Objects userBO and userEntity. I want to transfer the object values from userEntity to userBO and my requirement that serialization should not be lost while transferring the values. This is what I am doing. Please tell me is this correct?

```
public static UserBO converUserEntityToUserBO(UserEntity userEntity) {
    UserBO userBO = new UserBO();
    userBO.setUserId(userEntity.getUserId());
    userBO.setUserFile(userEntity.getUserFile());
    userBO.setUserDepartment(userEntity.getUserDepartment());
    return userBO;
}
```

UserBO.class

```
public class UserBO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3886993061934034729L;

    private int userId;
    private int departmentId;
    private byte[] userFile;
    private String dbAction;

    //getter and setter 
}
```

UserEntity.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_ENTITY")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4676281792392490908L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name="USER_DEPARTMENT")
    private String userDepartment;

    @Lob()
    @Column(name="USER_FILE")
    private byte[] userFile;

      //getter and setter

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every serializable class has a unique identification number associated with
it, which you have explicitly specified for both `UserBO` and `UserEntity` class:

```
public class UserBO implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3886993061934034729L;
...
}
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4676281792392490908L;
...
}
```

If you do not specify this number explicitly by declaring a static final long field
named `serialVersionUID`, the system automatically generates it at runtime by applying a complex procedure to the class.

The automatically generated value is affected by the `class’s name, the names of the interfaces it implements, and all of its public and protected members`. If you change any of these things in any way, for example, by adding a new method, the automatically generated serial version UID changes. And this will break the compatibility and can result in unexpected `InvalidClassExceptions` during deserialization.

But you have an explicit `serialVersionUID` value declared in both of your classes, which  guarantees a consistent `serialVersionUID` value across different java compiler implementations; so the method `converUserEntityToUserBO` will not cause any serialization issues while transferring data from `UserEntity` to `UserBO`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your both classes have the same fields java reflection can help to do in a better way. Try this.

```
public UserBO loadData (UserEntity userEntity) throws Exception{

    Method[] gettersAndSetters = userEntity.getClass().getMethods();
     UserBO userBO = new UserBO();
    for (int i = 0; i < gettersAndSetters.length; i++) {
            String methodName = gettersAndSetters[i].getName();
            try{
              if(methodName.startsWith("get")){
                 userBO.getClass().getMethod(methodName.replaceFirst("get", "set") ,  
       gettersAndSetters[i].getReturnType() ).invoke(userBO, 
                         gettersAndSetters[i].invoke(userEntity, null));
                    }else if(methodName.startsWith("is") ){
                        userBO.getClass().getMethod(methodName.replaceFirst("is", "set") 
                 ,  gettersAndSetters[i].getReturnType()  ).invoke(userBO, gettersAndSetters[i].invoke(userEntity, null));
                    }

            }catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

            }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            }

    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do same stuff with apache bean utils, please refer to example below.

** Here values of properties having same name across both DTO will only be copied from source into taget.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class BeanUtilsCopyPropertiesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FromBean fromBean = new FromBean("fromBean", "fromBeanAProp", "fromBeanBProp");
        ToBean toBean = new ToBean("toBean", "toBeanBProp", "toBeanCProp");

        try {
            System.out.println("Copying properties from fromBean to toBean");
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(toBean, fromBean);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(fromBean));
        System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(toBean));
    }
```

}